# R: running lm() keeping string values

Tags: string, r, lm

I have a data frame containing 3 fields:

```
data$name: string (a description)
data$y: numeric
data$x: numeric
```

I want to create a linear model for my data. It is very easy to run

```
mymodel <- lm(y ~ x, data=data)
```

but I want to be able to keep data$name in mymodel, so I can see its values when I ask for `mymodel$model`. If i run

```
mymodel <- lm(y ~ x + name, data=data)
```

then I will get many errors because R or the `lm()` function will treat `data$name` as factors.

Is there a way to do what I want? I don't want `data$name` to be used as factor; I just want the names to appear together with my data after the fitting.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rownames` to store this data in the data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(name=letters[1:10],x=1:10,y=15:24+rnorm(10,0,0.1))
rownames(data) <- data$name
mymodel <- lm(y ~ x, data=data)
mymodel$model
         y  x
a 15.19149  1
b 15.93323  2
c 16.91007  3
d 18.00176  4
e 19.02350  5
f 19.96446  6
g 20.92975  7
h 21.85556  8
i 22.99855  9
j 24.02255 10

predict(mymodel)
       a        b        c        d        e        f        g        h 
15.02702 16.01726 17.00750 17.99774 18.98797 19.97821 20.96845 21.95868 
       i        j 
22.94892 23.93916
```